# Identifying $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i k x} dx$ as Dirac delta distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

The expression $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i k x} dx$ is sometimes identified as the Dirac delta function. This identification is said "formal" or "symbolic", and some physics texts say that the theory of distribution makes this identification rigorous. So I read some texts on distributions and I think now I understand what delta function is as a distribution. However, I still cannot give any meaninig on the expression as a distribution. Is it possible to give a well defined meaning as a mathematical object to the expression?

Comment: I'm not sure but I believe: its the inverse Fourier transform of 1, but of course writing it formally as this integral doesn't make sense, so you define as a limit of an approximating sequence in $\mathcal D'$. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillatory_integral

Comment: @CalvinKhor So you introduce two ways. i) The actually "intended" by the expression may be the distributional Fourier transform of 1. ii) Intepreting the improper integral as a special kind of limit introduced in the Wikipedia page makes the expression rigorous. Am I right?

Comment: That's my impression but I'm not certain as I've only read about this in passing.

Answer (score 5):

The way to give meaning to an expression as a distribution is to see its effect on a test function.  If $\phi(x)$ is a test function (a member of the Schwartz space $\mathscr S(\mathbb R)$), then the action of the formal expression $T = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikx}\; dx$ on $\phi$ is obtained by integration (and switching the order of the integrals):
$$ T(\phi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \int_{-\infty}^\infty dk \; \phi(k) e^{ikx}
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \; \hat{\phi}(-x/(2\pi)) = 2 \pi \phi(0)$$

Comment: Isn't it still "formal"? There is a distribtion $T$ defined as $\left< T, \phi \right> = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \int_{-\infty}^\infty dk \phi(k) e^{ikx}$. Do you mean I have to identify any occurrence of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikx} dx$ in an integral with the action of $T$ even if the integral itself is not well defined? For example, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dk \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \phi(k) e^{ikx}$ is sometimes found in physics texts but it is meaningless if interpreted as it is.

Answer (score 2):

$$
   \langle \int_{-R}^{R}e^{ikx}dk,\varphi\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(x)\int_{-R}^{R}e^{ikx}dkdx \\
            = \int_{-R}^{R}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(x)e^{ikx}dx dk
$$
As $R\rightarrow\infty$ the above tends to $2\pi\varphi(0)$. So the truncated integral converges in the distribution sense to a scalar times the Delta function at $0$:
$$
      \int_{-R}^{R}e^{ikx}dk \rightarrow 2\pi\delta_{0}.
$$
The improper integral converges in the dual. It's an element of $\mathscr{S}^*$.